# Program not outputting correctly

Tags: c

My program doesn't output correctly when I enter 1 mile

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
int kilometers;

int miles;

printf("\n");
printf("Please enter the distance in miles: ");
scanf("%d", &miles);
printf("\n");

kilometers = 1.52 * miles;

printf("%d miles is equal to ", miles);

printf("%d kilometers", kilometers);
printf("\n\n");

return 0;

}
```

When I put 1 in for miles it should output to 1.52 kilometers but gives me 1 kilometer

Comment: hint: what kind of values are integers?

Comment: `int` and `"%d"` are for integers. If you want floating point values, try `double` and `"%lf"`

Comment: OT: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  Note: those functions return the number of successful 'input format conversion specifiers' ( the `%d` is a 'input format conversion specifier`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you are using `int` instead of `float` or `double`, therefore you won't get the precision that you require. Also your conversion for miles to km is incorrect; there are `1.60934` kilometers for every `1` mile.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

double kilometers;
double miles;

printf("\nPlease enter the distance in miles: ");
scanf("%lf", &miles);
printf("\n");

kilometers = 1.60934 * miles;

printf("%.2lf miles is equal to ", miles);
printf("%.2lf kilometers\n\n", kilometers);

return 0;

}
```